# How to remove Newline from a log in filter block using mutate gsub

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am trying to remove a newline from my log because my grok pattern only works if the newline is not present. For that, I'm trying to use gsub in mutate in my logstash.conf file.
Here is the snippet from my log:

```sh
fc26bc5f144412f8116fa95615d3c8c.india.in 21.211.112.223 2411:3a70:ab4:5706:5:69:4fg6:6701 2 132.10.30.2 - - - 0.081 [30/May/2019:00:01:01 
+0530] \"POST
```

Here is the snippet from my logstash.conf file:

```sh
filter
{
       mutate { gsub => [ "message", "
", "" ] }
       grok
       {
               match => {'message' => '%{IPORHOST:lbhost}'}
       }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps with `\\n`? (there's 2 \ since they need to be escaped in the logstash conf)

Comment: I checked with ```\\n``` also it is not working.

Comment: Normally you would use a literal newline, as in your mutate filter. However, if you have config.support_escapes enabled you should use \n

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the newline character **\n** as the value to be replaced. As stated in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-gsub.) any backslash in the config file must be escaped.

```
filter{
  mutate{
    gsub => [ "message", "\\n", "" ]
  }
  grok{
    match => { "message" => "%{IPORHOST:lbhost}" }
  }
}
```

In its core, your question focusses on how to use gsub of the mutate filter plugin to replace new lines from a field. So please distinguish between the gsub does not work as expected or your grok pattern still fails even after the gsub when stating that *it is not working*.

Answer (score 0):

Little late to the party but I hope this might help someone else.
The only problem with the gsub method is that it will strip "\n" from the entire string. Not just new lines but literal "\n" as well. Sometimes they are needed.
Another option is to use ruby.

```
ruby { 
    code => 'event.set("new_message", event.get("message").strip)'
}
```

This will strip trailing new lines as well as blank spaces into a new field called new_message.